# RaisePropertyChanged broadcast using incorrect Messenger

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

In **ViewModelLocator**:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMessenger, Messenger>();
```

In a property on a **view model**:

```
RaisePropertyChanged<string>("CurrentDrug", oldValue, value, true);
```

In **View model #2**:

```
this.messengerService.Register<PropertyChangedMessage<string>>(
    this, 
    this.HandleDrugChangedMessage);
```

**View model #2** never receives the broadcast message.  However, if I change view model #2 to:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<PropertyChangedMessage<string>>(
    this, 
    this.HandleDrugChangedMessage);
```

Then all is fine.

What do I do so that my messengerService that is passed in to the view models is the one that originally broadcasts the message, not the Messenger.Default one?

To show how messenger service is passed:

```
public class ViewModelNumberOne: ViewModelBase
{
    // dependency
    private IMessenger messengerService;

    // constructor
    public ViewModelNumberOne(IMessenger messengerService)
    {
        this.messengerService = messengerService;
    }
}

public class ViewModelNumberTwo: ViewModelBase
{
    // dependency
    private IMessenger messengerService;

    // constructor
    public ViewModelNumberTwo(IMessenger messengerService)
    {
        this.messengerService = messengerService;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, when you register the `IMessenger` interface, you are actually registering to the concrete type itself, but not to a specific instance of that concrete type.

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMessenger>(() => Messenger.Default);
```

With the above syntax, when SimpleIoC resolves `IMessenger`, it will do so with the `Messenger.Default` instance, preserving it as a singleton.  This will allow you to use your injected instance.